# Pseudo Code for visiting supermarkets

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, nearest-neighbor, greedy

I have been trying to write a functional pseudo-code for visiting a number of supermarkets where the following information is provided:

1. Number of supermarkets
2. Number of ingredients to be collected
3. Probability that the ingredients are in good condition
4. Probability that the ingredients are in acceptable condition
5. Prices
6. Budget

My initial approach was to tweak the nearest neighbour pseudo-code though the following expected result made it a little difficult for me to proceed:

1. Find the sequence of supermarkets to be visited
2. Show the ingredients that will be collected in each of those supermarkets.

My second approach was to use the greedy algorithm giving priority to the supermarkets with the highest chance of availability (Acceptable Probability + Good Probability).

Ignoring all other constraints (budget, prices), how can I give the expected second output:

**Which ingredients will be collected at which supermarket.**

Can anyone can point me to a better approach for a functional pseudo-code?

Comment: Deleted VBA Beginner - it adds nothing.  Removed [tag:vba] because until you show some code, it's not a VBA question.  Formatted numbered lists.  Improved formatting.

Comment: As the sequence of the supermarkets to be visited, apparently the problem includes the Traveling Salesman problem as a subproblem, although no distances are stated in the problem description.

Comment: Update: We used Nearest Neighbor to find an initial route, a probability rank list for each supermarket to determine where to collect each ingredient, four local search algorithms to improve the solution from the Nearest Neighbor, and two meta heuristic algorithms to improve those of the local search.
They worked fine and all instances tested were feasible except for one in the Nearest Neighbor sequence.

Thanks.